# update records using combobox and textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, combobox, textbox

This is my code using updating records using textbox and comboboxes, but it returns error
this error below
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ','

but when i checked my code i cant find any error kindly help me to revise thanks!

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
    Try

        ''update command
        sqlconn.Open()

        myCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE tblOfficeEquipmentProfile SET OE_Category = '" & cmbCategory.Text & "',OE_SubCategory = '" & cmbSubCategory.Text & "', OE_ID = '" & txtOEID.Text & "', OE_Name = '" & txtName.Text & "', OE_User = '" & txtUser.Text & "', OE_Brand = '" & cmbBrand.Text & "', OE_Model = '" & cmbModel.Text & "', OE_Specs = '" & txtSpecs.Text & "', OE_SerialNo = '" & txtSerialNo.Text & "', OE_PropertyNo = '" & txtPropertyNo.Text & "', OE_MacAddress = '" & txtMacAddress.Text & "', OE_Static_IP = '" & txtStaticIp.Text & "', OE_Vendor = '" & cmbVendor.Text & "', OE_PurchaseDate = '" & txtPurchaseDate.Text & "', OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear = '" & cmbWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text & "', OE_WarrantyStatus = '" & txtWarrantyStatus.Text & "', OE_Status = '" & txtStatus.Text & "', OE_Dept_Code = '" & cmbDeptCode.Text & "', OE_Location_Code = '" & cmbLocationCode.Text & "', OE_Remarks ='" & cmbRemarks.Text & "' WHERE OE_Category = '" & cmbCategory.Text & "',OE_SubCategory = '" & cmbSubCategory.Text & "', OE_ID = '" & txtOEID.Text & "', OE_Name = '" & txtName.Text & "', OE_User = '" & txtUser.Text & "', OE_Brand = '" & cmbBrand.Text & "', OE_Model = '" & cmbModel.Text & "', OE_Specs = '" & txtSpecs.Text & "', OE_SerialNo = '" & txtSerialNo.Text & "', OE_PropertyNo = '" & txtPropertyNo.Text & "', OE_MacAddress = '" & txtMacAddress.Text & "', OE_Static_IP = '" & txtStaticIp.Text & "', OE_Vendor = '" & cmbVendor.Text & "', OE_PurchaseDate = '" & txtPurchaseDate.Text & "', OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear = '" & cmbWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text & "', OE_WarrantyStatus = '" & txtWarrantyStatus.Text & "', OE_Status = '" & txtStatus.Text & "', OE_Dept_Code = '" & cmbDeptCode.Text & "', OE_Location_Code = '" & cmbLocationCode.Text & "', OE_Remarks ='" & cmbRemarks.Text & "'", sqlconn)
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Office Equipment Profile Successfully Updated Records")
        sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    DisableBoxes()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the query being weak because it is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, the error is in the `WHERE`. You should not use `comma` to separate the condition but instead use `Conditional Operator` such as `AND / OR`. example,

```
WHERE OE_Category = '' AND
      OE_SubCategory = '' AND
      OE_ID = '' AND ...
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
Dim  updateStatement As new System.Text.StringBuilder
updateStatement.Append("UPDATE tblofficeequipmentprofile " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("SET    oe_category = @oe_category, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_subcategory = @oe_subcategory, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_id = @oe_id, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_name = @oe_name, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_user = @oe_user, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_brand = @oe_brand, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_model = @oe_model, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_specs = @oe_specs, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_serialno = @oe_serialno, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_propertyno = @oe_propertyno, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_macaddress = @oe_macaddress, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_static_ip = @oe_static_ip, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_vendor = @oe_vendor, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_purchasedate = @oe_purchasedate, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_warrantyinclusiveyear = @oe_warrantyinclusiveyear, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_warrantystatus = @oe_warrantystatus, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_status = @oe_status, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_dept_code = @oe_dept_code, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_location_code = @oe_location_code, " & vbCrLf)
updateStatement.Append("       oe_remarks = @oe_remarks ")

myCommand = New SqlCommand(updateStatement.ToString(), sqlconn)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", cmbCategory.Text)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubCategory", cmbSubCategory.Text)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OE_ID", txtOEID.Text)
'' other parameters
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: i'll be updating the answer `:)`

Comment: please parametrized the values, to avoid sql injection, to make your code readble. I'm sure you have extra `=` in your query causing syntax error.

Comment: ill be trying your code, the parametrized one. since i havent done it even once. is that update answer complete? ill just need to add the other parameters?

Comment: try passing a value in one of your fields that has single quote on it, example `ian's place`. obviuosly your code will throw syntax error.

Comment: the answer in not complete, it just shows how to parameterized the values. you have to add more paramrters

Comment: how about smalldatetime where can i declare it that its not a string or integer i have one column which is smalldatetime

Comment: just only make sure the parameters are not enclosed with single quotes and declare it like this `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", youSmallDatetimeSample)`

Comment: kindly wait for the feedback sir, im already updating my code and updating the code above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27998/discussion-between-ivandinglasan-and-j-w)

Comment: sir it doesnt work this is the new link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941808/updating-using-sql-parameters-in-vb-net

Comment: this is another problem if you understand the error. It simply your code is fully working but the new problem is the value that violates `PK_tblOfficeEquipmentProfile` constraint.

Comment: what is the strucuture of your table?

Comment: how come it violates? simply the value already exists. Check the valuew of the primary key.

Comment: this is the structure of the table kindly look http://i143.photobucket.com/albums/r134/kyotomoko/untitled-1.jpg

Comment: can see it clearly because the resolution is too small. What is your primary key? Is it int?

Comment: OE_ID is the primary key, its varchar

Comment: i see now the problem, you have no `WHERE` clause and because of that it will update all record including the primary key causing to throw the exception.

Comment: kindly comment on the new link sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941808/updating-using-sql-parameters-in-vb-net

can you help me revise the code with the where clause