# updating using sql parameters in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters, combobox, textbox

my code returns error saying

> violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblOfficeEquipmentProfile'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'tblOfficeEquipmentProfile'.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand


    'parametrized update sql command
    Try
        sqlconn.Open()

        myCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE tblOfficeEquipmentProfile SET OE_Category = @OE_Category, OE_SubCategory = @OE_SubCategory, OE_ID = @OE_ID, OE_Name = @OE_Name, OE_User = @OE_User, OE_Brand = @OE_Brand, OE_Model =@OE_Model, OE_Specs =@OE_Specs, OE_SerialNo =@OE_SerialNo, OE_PropertyNo = @OE_PropertyNo, OE_MacAddress = @OE_MacAddress, OE_Static_IP = @OE_Static_IP, OE_Vendor = @OE_Vendor, OE_PurchaseDate =@OE_PurchaseDate, OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear=@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear, OE_WarrantyStatus=@OE_WarrantyStatus,OE_Status=@OE_Status,OE_Dept_Code=@OE_Dept_Code,OE_Location_Code=@OE_Location_Code,OE_Remarks=@OE_Remarks", sqlconn)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Category", cmbCategory.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_SubCategory", cmbSubCategory.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", txtOEID.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Name", txtName.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_User", txtUser.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Brand", cmbBrand.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Model", cmbModel.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Specs", txtSpecs.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_SerialNo", txtSerialNo.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_PropertyNo", txtPropertyNo.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_MacAddress", txtMacAddress.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Static_IP", txtStaticIp.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Vendor", cmbVendor.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate", txtPurchaseDate.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear", cmbWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyStatus", txtWarrantyStatus.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Status", txtStatus.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Dept_Code", cmbDeptCode.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Location_Code", cmbLocationCode.Text)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Remarks", cmbRemarks.Text)

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        MsgBox("Successfully Updated Records")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Your current `UDPATE` statement seems to be updated **all rows** of your entire table to the same values (since there is no `WHERE .....` clause in your `UPDATE`) ..... is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: yes sir it will update all rows based on changed on textboxes and comboboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check primary key of table tblOfficeEquipmentProfile

Based on primary filed you can update rest of the fields, means remove updation of primary key fileds

Comment: how about if i need to edit or update the primary key field of the table?

Comment: you can edit primary key but primary key do not allow to edit/add same value exist for that field in table, so before edit/add on primary key you need to check that new text.value is not exist

Answer (score 1):

Hi This Query Updates All Datas in table so if You Have Some ID Unique you can't Update With identical ID,  I think you need add Where Statement to this query.

Comment: OE_ID is my primary key with data type varchar

Answer (score 1):

Check where is utilized based on your primary field   OE_ID

myCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE tblOfficeEquipmentProfile SET OE_Category = @OE_Category, OE_SubCategory = @OE_SubCategory,  OE_Name = @OE_Name, OE_User = @OE_User, OE_Brand = @OE_Brand, OE_Model =@OE_Model, OE_Specs =@OE_Specs, OE_SerialNo =@OE_SerialNo, OE_PropertyNo = @OE_PropertyNo, OE_MacAddress = @OE_MacAddress, OE_Static_IP = @OE_Static_IP, OE_Vendor = @OE_Vendor, OE_PurchaseDate =@OE_PurchaseDate, OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear=@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear, OE_WarrantyStatus=@OE_WarrantyStatus,OE_Status=@OE_Status,OE_Dept_Code=@OE_Dept_Code,OE_Location_Code=@OE_Location_Code,OE_Remarks=@OE_Remarks

where OE_ID = @OE_ID", sqlconn)

```
   myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Category", cmbCategory.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_SubCategory", cmbSubCategory.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", txtOEID.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Name", txtName.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_User", txtUser.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Brand", cmbBrand.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Model", cmbModel.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Specs", txtSpecs.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_SerialNo", txtSerialNo.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_PropertyNo", txtPropertyNo.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_MacAddress", txtMacAddress.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Static_IP", txtStaticIp.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Vendor", cmbVendor.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate", txtPurchaseDate.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear", cmbWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyStatus", txtWarrantyStatus.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Status", txtStatus.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Dept_Code", cmbDeptCode.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Location_Code", cmbLocationCode.Text)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Remarks", cmbRemarks.Text)
```